# 503 Backend fetch failed on magento 2.3.0 site with varnish cache

Tags: apache, magento, amazon-ec2, magento2, varnish

http://tyanabelle.com returns `503 Backend fetch failed` but the **https** [counter part](https://tyanabelle.com) **DOES work** though.

I'm using **apache v2.4.37**
and varnish cache,
and the website is a **magento 2.3.0** vanilla website,
specifically all of that configuration comes from a [bitnami aws magento image](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/magento/).

- Here's my [**apache configuration**](https://gist.github.com/SudoPlz/6c65404981729f0b400f493b61616cf7#file-apache-conf)
- and in this file I've set my [**virtual hosts**](https://gist.github.com/SudoPlz/6c65404981729f0b400f493b61616cf7#file-vhosts-conf)
- and here's my [**varnish configuration**](https://gist.github.com/SudoPlz/6c65404981729f0b400f493b61616cf7#file-varnish-vcl)
- Here is the [varnish log](https://gist.github.com/SudoPlz/6c65404981729f0b400f493b61616cf7#file-sudo-varnishlog) after I run `varnishlog`.

Specifically if I remove this Rewrite from the **virtual hosts** file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://tyanabelle.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

I no longer receive 503 errors.

But I want to be able to redirect ALL (subdomain or non subdomain) calls to https.

Not sure if related, but on Route 53 (aws dns settings) I redirect all subdomain calls to the main domain like so:

[image: route 53]

but this shouldn't play a role.

The end desirable result is, I want ALL the following subdomains:

```
http://tyanabelle.com
http://www.tyanabelle.com
http://*.tyanabelle.com
https://tyanabelle.com
https://www.tyanabelle.com
https://*.tyanabelle.com
```

(**ALL of them**) to be rewritten as https://tyanabelle.com

I've spent the past 3 hours on this, please help.

Comment: Your Apache config does not show any sign that it's relaying traffic to Varnish via reverse proxy. So you've installed Varnish and changed port, then expect it to work? There's more to this, much more. Enough to say that it won't fit into an answer here.

Comment: We need to see Varnish configuration

Comment: @DusanBajic I edited my answer and included the varnish configuration and the main apache config file.

Comment: @DanielV. I included the main apache configuration too, didn't change the port manually, bitnami did, this is a well configured server implementation that I'm trying to customise a bit. The new port works, if only I remove the 4 lines of code I wrote above.

Comment: @SudoPlz the well configured server implementation that is giving er... configuration issues. I'd advise on building the stack on your own. Based on the recent config update I can only reiterate - you need at least `ProxyPass` somewhere to terminate SSL traffic before Varnish. Current situation is that you've misconfigured things in port 80 (thus it fails, likely because Magento is redirecting to HTTPS), and your Varnish is not used at all in port 443 (need `ProxyPass` but you're just serving things directly by Apache).

Comment: Try (just for test) adding `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^pub/health_check.php` immediately under `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: @DusanBajic do you mean like so?

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^pub/health_check.php
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://tyanabelle.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

I tried, what should I expect?

Comment: Yes, but I made a typo (there should be a leading `/`): `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/health_check.php`. Do you still get 503 (after httpd restart)?

Comment: Adding just `RewriteEngine On` `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pub/health_check.php` and `RewriteRule ^ tyanabelle.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]` results in a `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error, because the domain is now: `http://tyanabelle.com/tyanabelle.com/tyanabelle.com/`